# ESP32 I2S with a MAX98357

Tags: current, amplifier, esp32, speakers, i2s

I have hooked up an ESP32-WROOM to a MAX98357 I2S Amp. I'm using the [ESP32-audioI2S](https://github.com/schreibfaul1/ESP32-audioI2S) library playing from an SD card. ESP is USB powered while the amp is powered from a bench power supply. I'm using a 3W 4 Ohm speaker.

It works great, but I got confused when checking the current flowing through the amp. The amp can do 3.2W with a 4Ohm speaker at 5.5V.

I'm powering the amp with 5V, so I expect to get ~2.5W. So with a 4 Ohm speaker, I would expect to see 1.2A. While playing a song the max I saw with my multimeter was 72mAh. If I power the amp with 3.3V I get 96mA. That is about 0.36W.

Am I reading the current wrong or am I just not getting the full power? I've set the max volume in the library.

I've tried a 10W and a 15W speaker as well (all 4 Ohm), results are similar, but noticeably louder than the 3W.

[image: Power/Supply Curve]

Comment: Hmmm it maybe, that your multimeter can measure the "Audio-Signal" accurate enough. Tried a oscilloscope with a shunt resistor? Other way would be a pure sine-wave tone (fixed 50Hz e.g) and the mutlimeter in AC-Mode.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Tried both of your suggestions. A multimeter with a 50Hz sine gave me 120mA, while the shunt method produced 300mA